# MissingManifestResourceException through SmartDeviceProject?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am new to SmartDeviceProject. So When i try to connect MySQL to my project, MissingManifestResourceException through in Connection.open in below code?.

```
 string connectionString = "server=192.168.1.100;database=mcubic;User Name=mcubic;Password=mcs@2011$;";
            string query = "select b.Outlet_Master_Name from mcs_user_outlet a,outlet_master b where a.Mcs_User_Outlet_User_Id=3 and a.Mcs_User_Outlet_Outlet_Id = b.Outlet_Master_Id";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(Reader[0].ToString());
            }
            connection.Close();
```

How do i solve this,. I am imported MySql.Data.CF.dll for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via Krish Kapadia from MSDN forums:

Solution :

1. MySql's version 5.2.7.0 is the stable version. I use dll of this version. Other versions have many problems. so first I download dll of that version from mysql site.
   here is the link :

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.2.html

1. I have inserted one entry in 'mysql.user' table in which hostname will be '%' (means any user can connect to mysql). If you don't want to insert entry with hostname then you have to insert for all ip addresses who should be allowed to connect to mysql.
2. After inserting entry in 'mysql.user', I restarted MySQL service.
3. And then trying to connect to mysql and Connected....

source: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/netfxcompact/thread/66f6386a-9963-4c2f-8d39-1c507a26a6c7

Comment: No use sir. mysql.data.cf.dll not found in that.